# Change layout of Infinite Container

Tags: codenameone

I am adding elements to my infinite container and they add vertically by default. But, I would like to change the infinite container from adding elements vertically and it adds horizontally. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
ic.setLayout(BoxLayout.x());
ic.setScrollableY(false);
ic.setScrollableX(true);
```

This lays the container horizontally. I'm not sure if this was tested but it should work.

Comment: Hi Shai, it looks like your answer is cut in the ending. Is something missing in the last sentence?

Comment: Damn. I removed that second sentence but I don't recall what I was thinking when writing that... Should have installed better logging software in brain ;-)